# Why is there no glClear() and glClearColor() method in GL30?

Tags: opengl, libgdx, opengl-es2, opengl-es3

In the `GL30` interface, both the methods `glClear()` and `glClearColor()` are absent. I tried to call the method `Gdx.gl30.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` inside `render()` but it threw me a null pointer exception. So I checked the interface. There's no `glClear()` method in `GL30`. Only in `GL20`. But OpenGL documentation says that [they](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glClear.xhtml) [are](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glClearColor.xhtml) supported in both v2.0 and v3.0. Why is it not included in LibGDX?

Comment: Could you include the code that you're trying to use that isn't working?

Comment: Maybe LibGDX doesn't separate GL functions by version ? So it will be something like `LIB.gl.glClear()` ?

Comment: @MattJensJensen I tried to call the method `Gdx.gl30.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` inside `render()` but it threw me a null pointer exception. So I checked the interface. There's no `glClear()` method in `GL30`. Only in `GL20`.

Comment: @Russoul But the `gl` in `Gdx` is a `GL20` object.

Comment: Have you set `config.useGL30 = true`?

Comment: @WeirdElfB0y, You're entirely welcome, hope you encounter smooth sailing from there!

Comment: @Russoul Now I got what you were saying. Thank you.

Comment: @Russoul I think yours was the apt explanation to this question. If you convert your comment to an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, then it won't compile. If you got a NullPointerException then that means it does exist!

Comment: @immibis Yes, that sounds obvious to me too now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibGDX is primary written in java, so it binds OpenGL functions to java methods. In the process of binding LibGDX is not required to keep original namespaces (java's equivalent of c/c++ namespace is package). LibGDX has a few classes which contain bindings to OpenGL functions and fields. Those classes extend each other: class containing bindings to the most recent supported version of OpenGL inherits a class with a prior version.

Lastly, GDX instantiates the last subclass so you can call any GL function from there not bothering about which specification of OpenGL implements it.

Also ,as said in another answer, you should config GDX to enable functions of OpenGL 3.0:

```
config.useGL30 = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

You must configure GDX to use GL30 prior to calling functions on `Gdx.gl30`:

```
config.useGL30 = true;
```

`com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL30` does not contain `glClear` and `glClearColor` in its interface because it is a subclass of `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20` and those functions are inherited from `GL20` therefore there is no need to define them in `GL30`'s interface.

See the [Gdx docs](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/GL30.html) for Methods inherited from interface com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20.

Comment: This solved the null pointer exception. Thanks! But it doesn't really answer the question I asked.

Comment: I've added the additional answer for those elements in your question.